# Change name of dependency jar before upload on remote repository

Tags: deployment, maven-2, build, jar

Here, the story of my problem :

I want to upload a jar with a pom.xml with deploy command, but i want the jar uploaded doesn't contains in this name the version number.

For example, the pom.xml for the jogl.all.jar :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
<artifactId>jogl.all</artifactId>
<version>2.0-b526-20111018</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging> 
<name>Jogl</name>
</project>
```

My deploy cmd :

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file  
  -Durl=http://maven.iscpif.fr/thirdparty/ 
  -DrepositoryId=maven.iscpif.fr 
  -DgroupId=org.jogamp.jogl 
  -DartifactId=jogl.all 
  -Dversion=2.0-b526-20111018 
  -Dfile=./jogl.all.jar 
  -DpomFile=./pom-jogl-all.xml 
  -Dpackaging=jar
```

The deployed jar equal here : `jogl.all-2.0-b526-2011108.jar`

But, when i call this dependency i want maven try to download a jar with this name : `jogl.all.jar`

Thanks for your advice :)

SR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the artifact name if you are deploying to a remote repository. This would break the way maven works.

Refer to @Pascal's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364363/how-to-stop-maven-renaming-installed-jars/2364493#2364493) in [this related SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364363/how-to-stop-maven-renaming-installed-jars) as well.

You can change the name of the dependant jars while including them in the distribution using maven assembly plugin by using the property `outputFileNameMapping`. Something like the following:

```
   <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, do you have an idea on how i can change the name of jar before adding them into my jar with assembly plugin ?